# How to link Pycharm with elasticsearch-py

Tags: elasticsearch-dsl

I have installed elasticsearch 2.3.3 on ubuntu 15.10. I am switching from intellij to Pycharm 2016.1.4. How can i configure pycharm such a way that use libraries such as elasticsearch-dsl?

Answer (score 0):

Preference -> Project Interpreter, search 'elastic search'. Should pop up up as the 6th or so option.